# Limit of the sequence $n(e^{1/n}-1)$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How can I evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\left(e^{1/n} - 1\right)$$

I have tried it applying the Squeeze Theorem but I can't seem to get anywhere with that.

Comment: Is the limit as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: just take the $n$ in the denominator and go for Lhopitals rule!! if $n$ tends to $\infty$

Comment: Hint: This is also $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-e^0}{h}$

Comment: Yes Varun Iyer. But I can't use L'Hopital with sequences.

Comment: @Eduardo yes you can. You're essentially describing a limit, not a sequence

Comment: L' hopitals rule is true for any real number and n is an integer so you can use L'hopitals rule

Comment: We haven´t seen L´Hopital in our calculus class.

Comment: Series expansion of exponential function is an alternative to L'hopitals rule!!

Answer (score 4):

Write $h = \frac{1}{n}$ then we are looking for the limit $$\bbox[10px, border: blue solid 1px]{\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h} - e^0}{h} = 1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\exp(x)\underset{x\to 0}{=}1+x+o(x)$, one has: $$\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=1+\frac{1}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
Therefore, one gets: $$n\left(\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-1\right)=1+o(1).$$
Finally, one has: $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}n\left(\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-1\right)=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{1/n}-1}{1/n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(-1/n^2)e^{1/n}}{-1/n^{2}}=1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

According to your following question, your sequence is defined as:

$$a_n = n\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)$$

You're trying to essentially find the limit of $a_n$ as $n\to\infty$.

As a limit, this can be represented as:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Direct substitution yields $\frac{0}{0}$. Therefore, we can use L'Hopitals Rule:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}*\left(-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{-\frac{1}{n^2}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$$

Comment if you have questions.

Answer (score -1):

Notice, 
let $\frac{1}{n}=t$,  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\left(e^{1/n}-1\right)$$$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{e^{1/n}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\left(1+\frac{t}{1!}+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\ldots\right)-1}{t}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\left(\frac{t}{1!}+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\ldots\right)}{t}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\left(1+\frac{t}{2!}+\ldots\right)=1+0=\color{red}{1}$$